# How to avoid passing large number of arguments in method using MVP approach

Tags: android, mvp

I have a registration screen with large number of registration fields, and when user click register button, I pass field values to presenter. In presenter I validate these values and create an object. The problem is a large number of arguments in register() method. I think that I should avoid this situation, but I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could explore the [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).
It allows to keep the code clean when you need to pass a big number of arguments.
It's also very useful when you don't know the exact number of arguments that will be passed, because some of them might not be mandatory.

In practice, you would have something like

```
MyObject myObject
void register() {
    myObject = MyObject.Builder(<mandatory arguments>)
               .argument1(<argument 1>)
               .argument2(<argument 2>)
               ...
               .create();
    if (myObject == null) fail();
    else dosomething();
}
```

Comment: main problem in not creating object, but passing arguments to presenter. I could create model object in view and pass it to presenter, but according to MVP I should move all logic (i.e. validation and creating objects) to presenter layer

Comment: Mmmm maybe i'm not expert enough of MVP, but I think that if you have a view that asks for some data to the user, it necessarly has to send these information to the presenter, but it does not need to be an object itself. I may be wrong but if in the view you create an object by using builder pattern, the validation and the logic is made inside create(), so the view does not to be aware of any logic, just needs to check if the created object is null or not. I don't really know if the create() method is part of presenter or model, though.

Comment: If I create my local Entity in view, It would be impossible to replace this entity object with another without editing view. View shouldn't know about entity objects, business logic etc. And I think that entity object model shouldn't  have any logic inside

Comment: What I think - as non-expert as I said - is that the view creates an object that is defined elsewhere, with its own logic. The view just limits its knowledge to the arguments are needed to create it, doesn't know how they are managed. In the MVP logic you could entirely change the logic inside the definition of the object, without changing a bit of the view, but you still ned an interface to make the different layers talk to each other. This - I think - is valid no matter if you 100 or just 1 parameter: some how the view must hold some variables and communicate them to the other layers.

Answer (score 0):

One way I have done this previously is to use a TextWatcher on each field that has to be completed:

```
myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        presenter.myEditTextChanged(s.toString());
    }
});
```

Then have the corresponding methods in the presenter update your entity.  This way when the user finally clicks register all the details will already be waiting in your presenter.

It also has the advantage that you can do validation as the user progresses - ie the register button isn't enabled until all fields are valid.

If you are using ButterKnife, RxBinding or DataBinding the code is more succinct as well.